Infinitesimal neighborhood and Ext group
$\DeclareMathOperator\Ext{Ext}$Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety and $\iota\colon Y\subset X$ be a smooth closed subvariety. It is well-known that there is a spectral sequence
$$E_2^{p,q}=H^p(\bigwedge\nolimits^q N_{Y/X})\Rightarrow \Ext^{p+q}(\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y, \iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y).$$
Question: If this spectral sequence degenerates at $E_2$-page and we take $i=2$, then how to describe explicitly the embedding
$$H^1(N_{Y/X})\to \Ext^2(\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y, \iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y)?$$
My guess is that for any $p\in H^1(N_{Y/X})$, its image in $\Ext^2$ is given by the composition
$$\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y\to \iota_*N^*_{Y/X}[1]\to \iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y[2]$$
where the first map $\iota_*\mathcal{O}_Y\to \iota_*N^*_{Y/X}[1]$ corresponds to the second infinitesimal neighborhood of $Y$ in $X$ cut out by $I^2_Y$ and the second map is given by the dual of $p$ shifted by $1$.
The above guess looks natural, however, I do not know how to prove this rigorously. Is there any reference for this?

The target of the embedding is the cokernel of the map from $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ to the Ext group.  If you are asking about a natural lift of this map to the Ext group, perhaps you should read about the semiregularity map of Severi, Bloch, et al.

You may be interested in the paper "When is the self-intersection of a subvariety a fibration?" by Arinkin and Căldăraru. They describe when the associated filtration $\iota^\iota_\mathcal O_Y$ splits in the derived category $D(Y)$, and when it splits they in principle give the map you seek.

There is no such map. In fact, the spectral sequence gives you a filtration on $\mathrm{Ext}^2(i_*\mathcal{O}_Y, i_*\mathcal{O}_Y)$ with three factors:
$$
\mathrm{Ext}^2(\mathcal{O}_Y, \mathcal{O}_Y),\quad
\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_Y, N_{Y/X}),\quad
\mathrm{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_Y, \wedge^2N_{Y/X}),
$$
so the space $H^1(N_{Y/X})$ is just the factor in the middle.
Even in the simpler case, where $Y$ is a divisor in $X$, you only have an exact sequence
$$
\dots \to 
\mathrm{Ext}^2(\mathcal{O}_Y, \mathcal{O}_Y) \to
\mathrm{Ext}^2(i_*\mathcal{O}_Y, i_*\mathcal{O}_Y) \to 
H^1(N_{Y/X}) \to \dots,
$$
so if the first map is injective and the second map is surjective (which happens when the spectral sequence degenerates), so that this becomes a short exact sequence, it doesn't have a canonical splitting.

@LSpice: Thanks for editing and the comment, but I realized that I misunderstood the question, so I rewrote the answer.
